# Upload image attachment and send it via wp_mail

Tags: php, html, wordpress, post, wp-mail

I'm trying to make a form where the user will be able to attach image file and then the image will be send on e-mail as attachment via wp_mail.
Here is what I've done so far:
The code for the attachment button:

```
<div class="attachment-row">
   <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" class="input-field" name="file">
   </form>
</div>
```

The code for moving the image and sending it as attachment:

```
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/uploads/'.basename($_FILES['file']['name']))
            $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/uploads/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $mailResult = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
```

And here is how I receive the image ( blank file instead of image attachment ). I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any kind of help is welcomed. Thanks!

[image]

Edit - I've also tried this way(to save the file name into variable)but it still doesn't work.

```
    $target_dir = WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/uploads/";
    $image_name=$_FILES['file'['name'];
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

To note that when I check my /wp-content/uploads/ folder the images that I've attached is not there - I guess the image is not saved but I cant figure out why.

Edit again-I've tried this way too but it don't work again:

```
           if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
                echo "noo";

            }
            
            $uploadedfile       = $_FILES['file'];
            $upload_overrides   = array( 'test_form' => false );
            $movefile           = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
            
            if( $movefile ) {
                echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
                var_dump( $movefile);
                $attachments = $movefile[ 'file' ];
                $mailResult = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
            } else {
            }
```

and the html form:

```
       <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        <input type="file" class="input-field" name="file">
                                    </form>
```

I'm stuck and I can't figure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: You save it as `'/uploads/' . basename($_FILES['file']['name'])`, but send as `'/uploads' . $_FILES['file']['name']`. Save path to variable and use it everywhere

Comment: @Justinas, I've tried that way but it still does not work: `$target_dir = WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/uploads/";$image_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file); `   Also, if i check my /wp-content/uploads/ folder, the image is not saved there

Comment: Actually, WordPress has its own upload functions that you could use, e.g. [`media_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/#comment-534) or [`wp_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_upload/#comment-1294) if you just want to upload the image without having to create an *attachment* (post of the `attachment` type) for that image.

Comment: I've tried that too, don't work, the image is not added as attachment in the email and I got :  ["error"]=> string(34) "Specified file failed upload test." }

Comment: @user15480222, did you actually upload a valid image file with a valid name, e.g. `image.jpg`?  If yes, then try debugging `wp_mail()` like [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_failed/#comment-2051). But looking at your original code, it seems like `move_uploaded_file()` may have failed, so does the `uploads` folder exist and is writable via PHP? Try uploading a very basic (small) PNG/JPG image?